# Changing the character value to numeric for set of variables

Tags: r, csv

I am new to `R` and need help on how to convert character values to numeric.

I am reading 19 variables from a `CSV` file and they contain following values:

```
EXTREMELY IMPORTANT-10   ----> This should be actually value 10
9
8
and so on
NOT AT ALL IMPORTANT-01  ----> This should be actually value 01.
```

Now I need to change values of all these 19 variables from character to numeric
I have written following code and it is giving me error.

```
path <- "C:/Rajesh-Pandit/SPSS-Trial/BANKING/Salary-Account"
setwd(path)

library(foreign)

final_data <- read.csv("Rajhi-R.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")
str(final_data)

x <- (as.data.frame(final_data[,c(15:33)]))

summary(x)

y <- as.matrix(19)
importance <- as.matrix(19)

for(i in (1:19)){
  if (x[i] == "EXTREMELY IMPORTANT-10")   {y[i] <- 10}
  else if (x[i] == "NOT AT ALL IMPORTANT-01")  {y[i] <- 1}
  else if (x[i] == "02") {y[i] <- 2}
  else if (x[i] == "03") {y[i] <- 3}
  else if (x[i] == "04") {y[i] <- 4}
  else if (x[i] == "05") {y[i] <- 5}
  else if (x[i] == "06") {y[i] <- 6}
  else if (x[i] == "07") {y[i] <- 7}
  else if (x[i] == "08") {y[i] <- 8}
  else if (x[i] == "09") {y[i] <- 9}
}
y

importance <- y
```

Basically `x[i]` character values are not changing to `y[i]`. Please give me feedback as to why for and if are not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
library('dplyr')
library('purrr')
library('magrittr')
# use map_if() if you want to round all numeric columns/vectors into 2 decimals
x %<>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>% map_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
```